# How to nest each statements with single dimensional arrays? (handlebars/node.js)

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js

I'm trying to loop through one array to create a series of columns, and then in each column populate a select menu with a list of images.

Here is the code I'm using to render the view;

```
 var text = ['one', 'two', 'three']
 var imgs = ['img1.png', 'img2.png', 'img3.png']

 res.render('validate', {test: text, images: imgs});
```

And the handlebars code;

```
<div class="column-container">
    {{#each test}}
        <div class="column">
            <h1>{{this}}</h1>

            <select>
                {{#each images}}
                    <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
                {{/each}}
            </select>
        </div>
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

When running this code, the first each statement is the only one recognised, and the select menu's in each column return empty.

First time using a template engine, so not sure if the each helper is intended to be used this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `../` to climb up the namespace ladder i.e get out of looping scope.

```
    . 
    .
<select>
    {{each ../images}}
        <option value="{{this}}">{{this}}</option>
    {{each}}
</select>
    .
    .
```